# Can you identify this handle-like LEGO piece?

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone help me identify the name and part no of this piece? I’ve tried looking in BrickLink for handles, guns, bars. Can’t think of any other way to describe it.

[image: Struggling to find name and part no for this piece, can anyone help?]

Answer (score 6):

Definitely on bricklink:
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60849#T=C
However, not as a minifig weapon but a minifig utensil
[image: hose nozzle]

Comment: Thank you Michael. Didn’t think to look under hose or nozzle.

Comment: Yes, I think this was used on some tanker truck and fuel pump builds, and possibly also fire trucks.